# Android MenuItems doesnt close after backpress

Tags: android

This issue occurred in Lollipop. I have and activity extending other activity which extends Base Activity. Base activity has a menu item, which is show in all activities. Problem is, if i click anywhere else apart from menu item or even back pressed, nothing happens menu item stays, If i click on menu item, associated actions happens and item closes. I need to close it, if i click anywhere else on screen. Is it a bug, or do i have to write a layout listener

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.base_menu, menu);
        if(SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance().getLoginStatus(this)) {// included logut option only if login is true
        menu.findItem(R.id.login_base).setVisible(false);
        }else{
            menu.findItem(R.id.logout_base).setVisible(false);
        }

        return true;


    }
```

I was using this style for overlap anchor

```
   <!--<item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/PopupTheme</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4.0dip</item>

        <item name="android:background">@color/jb_whit</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

I Removed it, and the problem is gone, but i need dropdown offeset.

Comment: can u post your menu item code

Comment: edited my code. removed style and now its working, but problem with offset

Answer (score 0):

[Refer here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

```
super.onBackPressed();
```